# C game and matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I have this matrix (original photo at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Ssu.png ):

```
{
  {   0,   1,   0,   2,   0,   3,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   4,   5,   6,   5,   4,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   7,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  26,  25,  24,  23,  22,  21,  20,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  27,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,  41,  42,  43, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,  39,   0,   0,  24,  23,  22,   0,  16,  15,  14,   0},
  {   0,  35,  36,  37,  38,   0,   0,  25,   0,  21,   0,  17,   0,  13,   0},
  {   0,  34,   0,   0,   0,  28,  27,  26,   0,  20,  19,  18,   0,  12,   0},
  {   0,  33,  32,  31,  30,  29,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  11,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,   0},
  {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 254,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0},
}
```

The soldier spawn at the number 254 in the matrix then after this, he will follow the numbers which represent the road.

The road that the soldier will have to follow will be the number 4 then 5 then 6 etc... and to do that, the soldier will go to the point around him where the number is the highest.

The soldier is represented by a number, we can say It's 230. I want to do a function that will move the soldier by one number only.
For example, if the soldier spawn, then he is at the number 254, so there will be no more number 254 because the number 230 will have the point. When i will call the function, the soldier, so the number 230 will be at 4. then again, when i will call the function, he will be at 5. and each time the soldier moves, the point where he was, will be equal to the number he moved to minus 1.

This is what i have done :

```
int point_around[4];
for( i=0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
    for( j=0 ; j < 15 ; j++){
        if( matrix[i][j] == 230){
                
                /* in point_around array we have the points around */
                get_point_around(matrix[i][j], point_around);

                /* looking for the max point, around the number 230 */
                /* sort the array to have the max point */
                size_tab=4;
                while( size_tab> 1 ){ 
                    for( k=0 ; k <  size_tab-1 ; k++ ){
                        if( point_around[k] > point_around[k+1] ){ 
                            tmp = point_around[k];
                            point_around[k] = point_around[k+1];
                            point_around[k+1] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                    size_tab--;
                }

                max = point_around[3];
               
                if( max == matrix[i-1][j] ){
                    matrix[i-1][j] = 230;
                } 
                else if( max == matrix[i][j+1] ){
                    matrix[i][j+1] = 230; 
                }
                else if( max == matrix[i+1][j] ){
                    matrix[i+1][j] = 230;
                }  
                else {
                    matrix[i][j-1] = 230;
                }  
                                    
                matrix[i][j] = max - 1;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when he will move to the right, so i call the function one time for him to move one time, he will move many times because of the j loop. I don't know how i can fix this.

Comment: 4 nested loops seems excessive. My approach to this would be, write a function to consider the current position, look in the surrounding 8 boxes (be careful to stay in bounds!) for the largest number, then move there. Call that function in a single loop until the end of the road is reached... which I'm not sure you've defined. What is the end of the road, when there are no more higher numbers than the one you just moved to?

Comment: Where do you track the soldier's current location?

Comment: Do the solders stack?

Comment: I made this.  It doesn't do it the same way you did but it works.  https://onlinegdb.com/SyfFMehrd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to finish the double loop once you've found a match...
Various choices:
You could follow one of the comments, by putting this in a function (you can then just 'return' once you've found the match).
Or you could adjust what you have with a break; and a check on the outer loop:

```
 int point_around[4];
 int max=-1;    // while <0 we know we've not found a match.
 for( i=0 ; i < 15 && max<0 ; i++){   // the max<0 checks in case we found a match
     for( j=0 ; j < 15 ; j++){
     ...
         matrix[i][j] = max - 1;
         break;
```

The break; finishes the j loop, but you'll still then be in the i loop so need an extra check on the i loop to detect if you should finish the loop.  I've used max as a test (as it will become positive once you find a match), but you could use a separate variable instead.